# Oracle error on startup "another startup/shutdown operation of this instance in progress"

Tags: oracle

I made a mistake in starting my local oracle instance. I did not set the `oracle_sid` before issuing `sqlplus "sys as sysdba"` and `SQL> startup`. Now I am unable to startup my instance. Please help me know how to shutdown the erroneous instance. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

close all sessions for this instance, or connect as sysdba and execute

```
shutdown abort
```

and then startup normally

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I logged in as sysdbs and entered the shutdown abort command. I received the errors "ORA-10997: another startup/shutdown operation of this instance inprogress
ORA-09967: unable to create or open lock file
Mac OS X Error: 13: Permission denied
I am still not doing something right. Can you suggested something more?  Thanks

Comment: Check ORACLE_SID equals your db name (echo $ORACLE_SID) and you have enough permissions (ls -l $ORACLE_HOME/bin). You should connect with command sqlplus "/ as sysdba"

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs/lkinst<instance_name>`
.
Then try  shutdown abort