# I am getting error while i am starting my database

Tags: oracle11g

SQL> startup
ORA-10997: another startup/shutdown operation of this instance inprogress
ORA-09967: unable to create or open lock file
Linux-x86_64 Error: 30: Read-only file system
SQL>

I tried shutdown and startup. But unable to start.. please help me.. !!

Comment: [Does this post help you anything?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4902916/2285592) or [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1135858?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

Shutting it down with the option "abort" would shut the current instance.   You may investigate more about the errors in the alert log file in the trace directory.

This might help you
http://psoug.org/oraerror/ORA-10997.htm

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by your filesystem not mounting properly.
[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4902916/2285592) recommends a shutdown abort but after doing that be prepared for recovery.
If your datafiles/control files are on your root filesystem then it will be tricky to mount/remount that partition but if they are separate then it shouldn't be hard to  remount them.
Have you checked your HDs for errors? [Smartd](https://serverfault.com/questions/445539/how-to-check-hdd-health-in-linux) can help you diagnose HD failures.
Also check [this document](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1120863.1) for reference.